# Variavel retornando 0 em arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Olá,estou aprendendo arquivos estou com dificuldade no uso do fwrite e fread,pois então a variável num1 esta me retornando 0 na estrutura de repetição e eu acho que fiz tudo direitinho =(

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{

 FILE *fp;
 int i;

 int num1[100];


 fp=fopen("Teste.bin","wb+");
 if(fp<0)

 {
     printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo!!!\n");
 }

 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
    printf("Digite valor");
    scanf("%d",&num1[i]);
    fwrite(&num1[i],sizeof(num1[i]),100,fp);
 }
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
     fread(&num1[i],sizeof(num1[i]),100,fp);
     printf("\nNumero: %d",num1[i]);
 }

 fclose(fp);
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: Mas qual era a sua intenção com este programa ? Cada `fwrite` que tem escreve o array todo

Comment: escreve 3 numeros e imprimir eles depois
algo bem simples

Comment: Mas para isso não precisa do array. Escrever com base no array só faz sentido se for para escrever os numeros todos de uma vez só e apenas uma vez, e para isso bastaria puxar os `fwrite` e `fread` para fora dos `for`. Isto é o `fwrite` a seguir ao primeiro `for` e o `fread` logo a seguir, antes do ultimo `for`.

Comment: ah ta, pensei fosse que nem arquivo txt que tinha que usar array para tudo =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem duas situações que precisa de ter atenção no seu código:

- Está a ler e escrever o array multiplas vezes nos `fors`:

  ```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      ...
      fwrite(&num1[i],sizeof(num1[i]),100,fp); //<--
  }

  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      ...
      fread(&num1[i],sizeof(num1[i]),100,fp); //<--
  }
  ```

  É importante lembrar que `fwrite(&num1[i],sizeof(num1[i]),100,fp)` escreve o array todo no arquivo, pois o terceiro parametro que é o `100` é a quantidade de elementos a escrever. Significa isto que está a escrever `3` arrays para o arquivo e depois lê os 3 arrays do mesmo arquivo. E estes arrays tem apenas alguns valores preenchidos, ficando o resto com o que estava em memoria.

  A solução é não fazer a escrita e leitura para arquivo dentro do `for`, ou trocar o array por variáveis soltas e gravar/ler uma a uma no `for`.
- Não está a fechar o arquivo que abriu para escrita para poder abrir como leitura. Isso até vai funcionar em algumas implementações mas noutras não. O correto é fechar com `fclose` e voltar a abrir com `fopen`, indicando um modo de leitura binária como `rb`.

Acertando esses dois problemas o seu código fica assim:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    int num1[100];

    fp=fopen("Teste.bin","wb+");
    if(fp<0) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo!!!\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("Digite valor");
        scanf("%d",&num1[i]);
    }

    fwrite(num1,sizeof(num1[0]),100,fp); //escreve uma vez
    fclose(fp); //fecha
    fp = fopen("Teste.bin","rb"); //abre para leitura
    fread(num1,sizeof(num1[0]),100,fp); //le uma vez

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("\nNumero: %d",num1[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

<sup>Obs: Não inclui o teste de erro de abertura de arquivo no segundo `fopen` por simplicidade mesmo.</sup>